# Problem while using getCurrentPosition geoLocation function within setInterval method for getting user current position with React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, setinterval

**Goal**

I need to get user location's latitude and longitude for display current position on route line. I used `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` npm modules for achieving this with React-Native. I need accuret location update with small frequncy that's why i choose setInrval method.

**Problem**

I used below function to get location with interval

```
watchCurrentLocation() {        
  try {
    this.intervalForWatchPosition = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Here for watch location based on Interval");
      // first try with without enableHighAccuracy
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          console.log("get user location with interval");
          const passengerInfo = {
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude
          }
          this.updatePassengerCoordinates(passengerInfo);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("Error while getting Current Location : ", error);
      },
      { timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 0 });
    }, 3000);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error while current location watch : ", err);
  }
}
```

this code `snip perfectly working with Android devices` but somehow its `not working with iOS`. In android its completly working as exprected. its gives location information on every 3 seconds and i easly update user on route line. But nothing happen with iOS devices as well as emulators. No error and No exeception at all.

In iOS its fire code but always return single location info as start point data. I have no idea what problem with iOS devices.

I have already used `watchPosition` but it will return result after long distance travel on route line. with that user jump from 1 location to another but now get navigated smoothly on route line so i dont want to use that. That's why i go with setInterval method with `getCurrentPosition` method. which is working fine with Android. I used below code for watchPosition

```
this._watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    const coord = [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude];
    this.setCurrentLocationToAsync(coord);
    const passengerInfo = {
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude
    }
    this.updatePassengerCoordinates(passengerInfo);
    },{
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0,
    distanceFilter: 1
    });
```

I used below version for implementing this functionality

`@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl: 6.1.2
react-native: 0.55.4`

Can anyone faced this kind of issues before? or any idea how to solved it on iOS?

**New Updated Code**

I have also try with recursive method to avoid setInterval method with async call like below but still its not work on iOS...!!!

```
watchCurrentLocation() {      
    getCurrentPositionTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      // first try with without enableHighAccuracy
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            console.log("get user location with setTimeout 1");
            const passengerInfo = {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
            this.updatePassengerCoordinates(passengerInfo);
            if (getCurrentPositionTimeoutHandle) {
              console.log("Timeout function exist so call that again 2");
              this.watchCurrentLocation();
            }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("Error while getting Current Location : ", error);
          //console.log("Error while executing timeout way method 3");
          this.watchCurrentLocation()
        },
        { timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0 });
    }, 3000);
}
```

Hope for getting something to solve it.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: What did you end up doing with this?  I have the same issue.  I got it to work by changing the interval to 15 seconds and using await for the results of getCurrentPosition but this is not a good solution.  It woulds fine in all browsers and Android but not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've tested using the getLocation() on it's own and still can't get a location?

If so, ensure check your `Info.plist` - You should have atleas, if not all of the following:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>CHANGEME: Location Always And When In Use Usage Description</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Endurance requires your location to track your progress</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>App requires background tracking</string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>CHANGEME: Motion updates increase battery efficiency by intelligently toggling location-services when device is detected to be moving</string>
```

Also, if you require background location - you'll need to enable this in capabilities in XCode.

**UPDATE**

I'm assuming that no JavaScript errors are thrown in the .catch() - if you are not looking at the JS Console, then please do - to ensure that you have currently caught exceptions. I'm also assuming your `console.logs()` are being printed right before you get a location??

If the code works correctly, then it will timeout after 10000 milliseconds - according to this code (meaning an exception will come back)

The OP has stated that absolutely nothing happens. If that is the case, then your permissions may be wrong. Ensure that you ***REBUILD*** your project after you have changed permissions.

**UPDATE 2:**

If the location that is coming back is not being refreshed, it could be safe to assume the device knows it has not moved. In simulator, you can try to simulate movement.

Navigating to Debug -> Location in the iOS Simulator's menu bar brings up some options for simulating a static location (Apple or Custom Location) or simulating a user riding a bicycle, running, or driving. The Custom Location option lets you input a static latitude and longitude:

Comment: this keys are already there in `Info.plist` file. i have tested with Backround location but nothing happen with that. I faced same issue.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project after?

Comment: Yes, clean and build again. but same issue faced. when i simply call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method, i get result properly but when i put this inside `setInterval`  during that it will remain to oldre location info.

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition` this both method work as expectation with different component. but when i want to get user location frequently i face this issue. So i think nothing related to permission as of now.

Comment: @JaydipshihVaghela - I've updated my answer, see if that works.

Comment: I used the same concept for location update on emulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181087/discussion-between-jaydipshih-vaghela-and-jrk).

Answer (score 0):

The reason of taking too much time for updating the location is using "enableHighAccuracy: true", this causes multiple sampling and takes a while. Changing it to "false" may result to a faster update for test your code. The second thing is that in emulator, you may need to change position info since you are using a not moving device.

Comment: I have already tested with `enableHighAccuracy: false` still does not get proper information that require. I have tested on moving device too but same thing happen with device also.

Comment: One last question, are you trying to test inside or outside(free space)?

Comment: i didn't get you. what you want to know?

Comment: One possible issue for gps is when you try to test in a covered building that signal is not receiving properly, I faced this issue before and got crazy about... however, the problem was I was testing my application inside my room,so as soon as I went out it solved and worked for me.

Comment: here not the case that you talking about. I know this happen but i have test on both inside and outside. from last 4 month i am working with gps location fetching. its work fine but this is totally different case to handle